# Is $664 million for 12 JF-17 block 3 reasonable?

Tags: pakistan

- [Pakistani JF-17s replace Iraq’s F-16 fleet](https://bulgarianmilitary.com/2023/07/09/unexpected-turn-pakistani-jf-17s-replace-iraqs-aging-f-16-fleet/)
- [iraq-might-buy-pakistans-jf-17-fighter-or-frances-rafale-or-both](https://www.forbes.com/sites/pauliddon/2023/07/10/iraq-might-buy-pakistans-jf-17-fighter-or-frances-rafale-or-both/?sh=685f60276b93)

> ... it’s rumored that Iraq has acquired 12 JF-17 Thunder Block III fighters, with the price tag speculated to be around $664 million.

This means each unit costs $55.33 million.

Isn't that expensive for a barely 4th gen jet?

- [iraq-to-reportedly-acquire-chinese-pakistani-jf-17-thunder-fighters](https://www.aerotime.aero/articles/iraq-to-reportedly-acquire-chinese-pakistani-jf-17-thunder-fighters)

This report says that the value of the contract is $1.1 billion. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Presumably the \$55 million unit cost includes not just the price of the jet (which is apparently around \$25 million) but also armaments, spare parts, and support agreements?

Comment: Military jet purchasess, especially fighter jets, can't be boiled down to a simple formula like that.

Comment: When you change the oil in your car, you also change the filter, and replace a gasket or two.  When you read engine codes, you use a specialized computer to read them. The easiest way to do major work on a jet engine -- which they need periodically -- is to remove it from the aircraft.  Which requires specialized equipment, and then specific tools & replacement parts & testing gear to do that work.  And on & on.  Since the buyer wants more than just *the 12 airframes* (and when something breaks, the plane is done), the whole panoply of support equipment & spares inevitably has to come with.

Comment: define "reasonable"

Comment: @RalphJ: that sounds like an answer 

Comment: When bidding for Inida's new fighter program in 2012, Rafale was only quoted about \$100M each, which was considered very expensive already because F22 was just about that number though a decade earlier (and B2 was "only" about \$1B each). The finalized price of Rafale was \$2.44M eventually and that's just nuts-on-the-next-level. If you compare $50M JF-17 with PakAF's \$40M J-10CE and yeah that's a hard sell, but if you see what's India and everyone else was paying for then I'd still call it a bargain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's reasonable.

International arms sales are usually done at significant markups - when they're not done for "free" (i.e. to attack the provider's opponent). Jet fighters aren't appliances, they are means of exerting control over some territory. These are things the purchasing country usually can't build on its own, at any cost.

The world's second-best-selling fighter, the Su-30 MKI, has cost India [about 2x what it costs Russia](https://militarywatchmagazine.com/article/india-s-su-30mki-costs-almost-twice-as-much-as-russia-s-new-su-30sm-here-s-why). That cost is higher in large part because it includes assembly in India - and, unlike Ikea flatpacks and kit planes, military customers pay extra for a chance to build the product themselves. That markup is still low in comparison to 3x+ for India's [Rafale deal](https://militarywatchmagazine.com/article/signs-of-backdoor-dealing-indian-opposition-slams-modi-government-for-secrecy-of-rafale-acquisition-deal-despite-enormous-costs).

Pakistan is on "enemy of my enemy" terms with the US, not too friendly with the EU or Russia, so China is its most reliable ally. The JF-17 is China's third-best fighter family, after the J-20 and Flanker clones. It's fitted with a full glass cockpit, a reasonable set of sensors, including IRST and reportedly a phased array in Block 3, can use most modern weapons, and has been successfully exported.

The F-16 - the best-selling fighter - has also been seen in [deals with unusually high unit cost](https://breakingdefense.com/2023/01/jordan-inks-deal-for-12-block-70-f-16s-from-lockheed-martin/). Overall, it's comparable to the JF-17 in size, but better kinematically and with better avionics in Block 70/72, and costs `$50M-$100M` (too many sources to cite here). `$55M` for the JF-17, about twice its flyaway cost, seems in line with this.

Contract price is different from unit price. Arms sales contracts include maintenance equipment, spares, often weapons, and ancillary hardware. The `$663M` is for the planes and the rest of the `$1.1B` is for these other items.

Comment: I think block 3 actually uses AESA, otherwise they might just buy the block 2 instead.